# Datatable still showing processing..., doesn't gen new data

Tags: javascript, grails, datatable, server-side

My HTML table

```
<table id="tbl" class=" table table-bordered">
    <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>id</th>
         <th>name</th>
         <th>lat</th>
         <th>lng</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

My JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#tbl").DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax":{
        "url" :"${createLink(controller:'Geography',action:'abccc')}",
        "type": "post",
    },
    columnDefs: [
        {"targets": 0,"searchable": false}
    ]
});
```

});

My Server (controller):

```
def abccc(){
    def listprovince = listprovince()
    render listprovince as JSON
}

def listprovince(){
    def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
    try {

        JSONObject result = new JSONObject()
        JSONArray data = new JSONArray()

        int start = 0, length = 0


    String error = ""
    long recordsTotal = 0
    int recordsFiltered = 0
    int draw = 1

    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("select * from geo_province where deleted = false")

    //1. get data with range limit
    if(params.start){start = Integer.parseInt(params.start)}
    if(params.length){length = Integer.parseInt(params.length)}
    query.append(" limit "+start+" ,"+length+"")
    println "query.toString(): "+query.toString()

    def province = sql.rows(query.toString())
    if(province){
        for(p in province){
            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray()
            ja.push(p.id)
            ja.push(p.name)
            ja.push(p.lat)
            ja.push(p.lng)
            data.push(ja)
        }
    }else{
        error = "NO RECORD"
    }

    //2. total record of table
    String totalrecord_query = new StringBuilder("select count(*) as totalrecord from geo_province where deleted = false")
    def totalrecord = sql.rows(totalrecord_query.toString())
    if(totalrecord){
        recordsTotal = totalrecord[0].totalrecord
    }

    //put 5 return parameters for datatable
    result.put("draw", draw)
    result.put("recordsTotal", recordsTotal)
    result.put("recordsFiltered", recordsTotal)
    result.put("data", data)
    result.put("error", error)

    return result
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace()
    throw e
} finally{
    sql.close() 
}
}
```

At the page load, every thing ok, it will show up 10 first records of my table. And the query is generated ok:

`select * from geo_province where deleted = false limit 0 ,10`

But when I do some actions, like go to 2nd page. Server get sent params, makes correct query and return the same format JSON data. I use firebug and catch return data.

But my table doesn't change data, still show 10 first records and the `processing... alert` still appear. Like this. Please help me fix this

[image]

Comment: Can you post your json response data?  Specifically, does it match the returned data spec?  https://datatables.net/manual/server-side

Comment: @BrianKates: I am sure that JSON return is correc. Because at page load, datatable show ok .The page load: `{"draw":0,"recordsFiltered":64,"error":"","data":[[1,"",null,null],[2,"Hà Nội",null,null],[3,"Hồ Chí
 Minh",null,null],[4,"An Giang",null,null],[5,"Bà Rịa - Vũng Tàu",null,null],[6,"Bắc Kạn",null,null]
,[7,"Bắc Giang",null,null],[8,"Bạc Liêu",null,null],[9,"Bắc Ninh",null,null],[10,"Bến Tre",null,null
]],"recordsTotal":64}`

Comment: Page load is different than server side Ajax responses

Comment: @BrianKates: go to 2nd page: `{"draw":0,"recordsFiltered":64,"error":"","data":[[11,"Bình Định",null,null],[12,"Bình Dương",null,null
],[13,"Bình Phước",null,null],[14,"Bình Thuận",null,null],[15,"Cà Mau",null,null],[16,"Cần Thơ",null
,null],[17,"Cao Bằng",null,null],[18,"Đà Nẵng",null,null],[19,"Đắk Lắk",null,null],[20,"Đắk Nông",null
,null]],"recordsTotal":64}`

Comment: Are you echoing the draw value?  (Not trying to ask dumb questions just want to rule out obvious )

Comment: My English is not good. I don't understand exactly your question mean. You can see the first element of each element in `data` return. 1st time is first 10 records and 2nd time is the next 10 records

Comment: To keep it simple, turn server side off.  If that works (paging, etc), make sure you are following the server side API. Good luck

Comment: I have found the reason. Because of the `draw` parameters. Must = 0 or difference between each return JSON. After post 2 example above, everything gonna ok ( draw = 0 and after this question, I will always plus 1 for each request). Thank you @BrianKates

Comment: You're welcome. 10 chars